# Python Turtle: How do you set screen size in Turtle

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to make this simple game in Python Turtle, however, I am having much trouble in making the window stay the same size, and unresizable. I have made sure to check the second page of Google, and yeah.

```
import turtle


class Window:
    def __init__(self, dim):
        self.win = turtle.Screen()
        assert type(dim) == type((1, 2))
        self.win.setup(width=dim[0], height=dim[1])
        self.win.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, dim[0], dim[1])

    def init(self):
        self.win.mainloop()


a = Window((100, 100))
a.init()
```

That is my code, and hope you have a nice day!

Comment: I meant like I'm still asking a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `turtle.screensize()` like this:

```
import turtle

turtle.screensize(canvwidth=400, canvheight=400)
```

Comment: Yo thanks so much! 
It is a really old question and I don't need it at all anymore, but still... tysm!